# How to deal with mixed permissions while using rsync?

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, rsync

I have a directory which I wish to duplicate on a remote server using rsync. Incidentally, these files are put in the synced directory by use of a Samba share, from Windows clients.

I've created a user on both servers specifically to manage the rsync task.
I've enabled ssh key-based authorisation, without a passphrase, and the connection works as it should.

My issue is around the management and replication of permissions and ownership. I'm using the -a option to preserve those bits, which works well. The issue is that my transfer user may not have access to the files and directories on the local server, and will need extended privileges on the remote one.

I know I can set the transfer user to have passwordless sudo just for rsync, and know that there are rsync options such as `--super` `--fake-super`, `--rsync-path`. Alternatively, if I set the `force group` option on my samba share, I can guarantee that all the files are owned by the same group, and by adding my transfer user to that group, I can sort out the local end using group permissions. What's the normal/most sensible way to achieve this?